# Add rep in a tooltip on the username in the bounty banner

Tags: bug, reputation, bounties, tooltips

In most places of SE sites where a username is displayed and their rep score isn't displayed on the page, there is usually a tooltip on the username that shows their reputation.

However, at present, this is not true in the bounty notices, i.e. as shown here:

[image]

(from [this example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153196/why-do-spin-frac12-nuclei-have-zero-electric-quadrupole-moment).) This is

- mostly trivial to fix,
- good for consistency, and
- a situation where the bounty setter's rep actually vaguely matters.

In particular, it's quite different to have a 100-rep bounty set by a user with 5k rep, and to have the same 100-rep bounty set by a user with 90 rep who just lost three privileges by setting it. It's a valuable signal about the bounty setter's stake in the question and it's easy to provide.

Comment: I don't have an opinion on the core of the request here (yet), but I don't think you can draw any sort of conclusion on the value of a bounty based on the setter's reputation. "You still have 5k rep, so clearly you don't care about his" is dismissive, at best.

Comment: @AdamLear For sure. But "you gave up site privileges for this" is certainly signal. (Not important enough to merit printing on its own, because as you note the other extreme is not signal, but just put it there in case I ask in the usual way.) And even if not, it's still inconsistent behaviour - or do usernames show up unreptooltipped elsewhere?

Comment: Probably! (I don't know off hand, we link to users a lot and consistency hasn't always been a strong suit.)

Comment: Fair enough. Still, the convention exists, and this is one of the few situations where we're actually talking about rep.